# compare character strings extract differences into new column R

Tags: r, string, character, string-matching

Title might sound confusing, idea is more straightforward.

I am trying to compare address data. I have multiple addresses for the same person, I need to compare them. If they are equal, great. If they are not, I need to extract whatever is different into a new column.

There are data below that create the DF. Then, I use charmatch wrapped inside mapply to compare the addr2 to addr1, in both directions; if there are any differences , the addr_compX_Y columns = 1.

```
eg_data <- data.frame(
addr1 = c('123 Main St','742 Evergreen Ter','8435 Roanoke Dr','1340 N State Pkwy') , 
addr2 = c('123 Main St Apt 4','742 Evergreen Terrace','8435 Roanoke Dr Unit 5','1340 N State Pkwy')) 
eg_data$addr_comp1_2 <- mapply(charmatch, eg_data$addr1, eg_data$addr2)
eg_data$addr_comp2_1 <- mapply(charmatch, eg_data$addr2, eg_data$addr1)
```

The ideal end result dataframe would look like the second set of example data. I'd add something that extracts whatever is different if the addr_compX_Y do not equal 1.

```
eg_data <- data.frame(
addr1 = c('123 Main St','742 Evergreen Ter','8435 Roanoke Dr','1340 N State Pkwy') , 
addr2 = c('123 Main St Apt 4','742 Evergreen Terrace','8435 Roanoke Dr Unit 5','1340 N State Pkwy')) 
eg_data$addr_comp1_2 <- mapply(charmatch, eg_data$addr1, eg_data$addr2)
eg_data$addr_comp2_1 <- mapply(charmatch, eg_data$addr2, eg_data$addr1)
eg_data$diff1_2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA)
eg_data$diff2_1 = c(' Apt 4', 'race', ' Unit 5', NA)
```

I know how to compare, I know how to extract, but I am unsure as to how I do them both at the same time.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it, using a library called vecsets:

```
library(vecsets)
eg_data <- data.frame(
  addr1 = c('123 Main St','742 Evergreen Ter','8435 Roanoke Dr','1340 N State Pkwy') , 
  addr2 = c('123 Main St Apt 4','742 Evergreen Terrace','8435 Roanoke Dr Unit 5','1340 N State Pkwy'),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
eg_data$addr_diff1_2 <- mapply(vsetdiff, strsplit(eg_data$addr1, split = ""),
                              strsplit(eg_data$addr2, split = ""))
eg_data$addr_diff2_1 <- mapply(vsetdiff, strsplit(eg_data$addr2, split = ""),
                               strsplit(eg_data$addr1, split = ""))
```

outputs a list of characters:

```
              addr1                  addr2 addr_diff1_2        addr_diff2_1
1       123 Main St      123 Main St Apt 4                  , A, p, t,  , 4
2 742 Evergreen Ter  742 Evergreen Terrace                       r, a, c, e
3   8435 Roanoke Dr 8435 Roanoke Dr Unit 5               , U, n, i, t,  , 5
4 1340 N State Pkwy      1340 N State Pkwy
```

Comment: This is awesome, it will get me 90% of the way there. Only question - is there anything that will output the different characters together, IE not separated by commas? " Apt 4" and not " , A, p, t,  , 4" ? I can put them back together with paste, but if there is any package that'll do it automatically, rad.